# How to use existing teamcity database with new Teamcity server installation of 9.1 version

Tags: database, import, teamcity-9.0

Recently, I have moved to new server and installed latest Teamcity version 9.1. I want to import the same data into new installation but unable to connect to existing database. 
Followed the following links :-

```
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+an+External+Database

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014228/how-do-i-connect-teamcity-to-an-existing-sqlserver-2005-database
```

I can successfully connect to database but getting the following error:-

```
Found a TeamCity internal database when no system directory or an empty system directory is expected
Current Startup State
Startup status
Current step: TeamCity server startup error 
Next step: not defined yet 
Data Directory
Directory path: Z:\TeamCity\.BuildServer exists
Database properties file exists
Internal database file: not found
Database
Database type: default (using internal database)
Database connection URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://db02:2433/d01
JDBC driver version: 1.2 (jTDS Type 4 JDBC Driver for MS SQL Server and Sybase)
Database system version: 11.0.5058 (Microsoft SQL Server)
Versions
Software version: 727
Data directory version: unknown
Database version: 709 
Logs
Logs path: C:\TeamCity\logs
Using Windows server 2012
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: sounds like a support question

Answer (score -1):

If your teamcity install is corrupt (more specifically, your data directory), your database has become useless. The recommended course of action is:restore from backup and, failing that: reinstall and reconfigure.